# Is getattr/setattr/hasattr/delattr thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading

See this Singleton implementation：

```
if not hasattr(Singleton, "_instance"):                                    
    with Singleton._instance_lock:                                         
        if not hasattr(Singleton, "_instance"):                            
            Singleton._instance = Singleton()                                 
return Singleton._instance
```

It seems that "Singleton._instance = .."（something like setattr) and hasattr are atomic.
Or hasattr won't lead to a crash because of setattr.

But I cant find any to support above 'seems'.

Comment: Why not create the singleton on module import?

Comment: I didnt focus on singleton, but the getattr/setattr/hasattr/delattr.Is it thread-safe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Usually**, provided the object you call the operations on does not implement the [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), [`__delattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__detattr__) or [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) hooks in python, then yes, `hasattr`, `getattr`, `delattr` and `setattr` are atomic operations.

Any individual bytecode is an atomic operation as far as Python threads are concerned. The Python evaluation loop grabs the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) while interpreting opcodes.

You'd need to look at the bytecode to see where the boundaries lie:

```
>>> def foo():
...     if not hasattr(Singleton, "_instance"):
...         with Singleton._instance_lock:
...             if not hasattr(Singleton, "_instance"):
...                 Singleton._instance = Singleton()
...     return Singleton._instance
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (hasattr)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Singleton)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('_instance')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        64

  3          15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Singleton)
             18 LOAD_ATTR                2 (_instance_lock)
             21 SETUP_WITH              35 (to 59)
             24 POP_TOP             

  4          25 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (hasattr)
             28 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Singleton)
             31 LOAD_CONST               1 ('_instance')
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             37 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        55

  5          40 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Singleton)
             43 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             46 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Singleton)
             49 STORE_ATTR               3 (_instance)
             52 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 55)
        >>   55 POP_BLOCK           
             56 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
        >>   59 WITH_CLEANUP        
             60 END_FINALLY         
             61 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 64)

  6     >>   64 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Singleton)
             67 LOAD_ATTR                3 (_instance)
             70 RETURN_VALUE
```

The story doesn't end there; `hasattr` uses `getattr()` (tests for an exception), which in turn can invoke the Python `__getattr__` hook. Similarly, the `STORE_ATTR` opcode could end up calling a python `__setattr__` hook implementation. In both cases the GIL would be released again.

For default implementations (`Singleton` does not implement those hooks) the operations are atomic as Python C code handles the whole operation without falling back to Python and thus the evaluation loop (where the GIL might be released and locked again for another thread).

Of course, you could still be dealing with a custom C library that releases the lock during [object protocol operations](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html). That'd be a an unusual thing to do.

Comment: I don't get it. How can `CALL_FUNCTION` be atomic? It doesn't grab GIL for the whole lifetime of the func, does it?

Comment: I think the same: it depends on what the called function does with the GIL. If it keeps it, all is ok. If it releases it, it's not thread-safe. I'd suppose it is thread-safe, but that is subject to test.

Comment: @thg435: it does for C functions like `hasattr`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, but `hasattr` can invoke userland `__getattr__`. In this case it should be releasing GIL, right?

Comment: @thg435: True, I'll need to add that. :-)

Comment: Updated; I am doing this on the go in trains and planes and my head wasn't paying enough attention here.

Comment: Isn't most of this very specific to CPython though, I think that should be mentioned.

Comment: @Wessie: Yes, the GIL is entirely CPython specific. PyPy, Jython and IronPython are out of scope here.