# why the get the global `IOLoop` instance need to "double check" ?（Tornado 4.5.3 ）

Tags: python, tornado

```
@staticmethod
def instance():
    """Returns a global `IOLoop` instance.

    Most applications have a single, global `IOLoop` running on the
    main thread.  Use this method to get this instance from
    another thread.  In most other cases, it is better to use `current()`
    to get the current thread's `IOLoop`.
    """
    if not hasattr(IOLoop, "_instance"):
        with IOLoop._instance_lock:
            if not hasattr(IOLoop, "_instance"):
                # New instance after double check
                IOLoop._instance = IOLoop()
    return IOLoop._instance
```

In the method of tornado.ioloop.IOLoop,
why get a new instance after double check?
If I only check once as follow,what the problem happened ?

```
@staticmethod
def instance():
    with IOLoop._instance_lock:
        if not hasattr(IOLoop, "_instance"):
           IOLoop._instance = IOLoop()
    return IOLoop._instance
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872210/is-getattr-setattr-hasattr-delattr-thread-safe) is closely related, if not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The lock is protecting the manipulation of the singleton `IOLoop`. But since [it seems that `hasattr()` is usually atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872210/is-getattr-setattr-hasattr-delattr-thread-safe), we can safely check for the existence of the instance without being *required* to lock the mutex. This is good, since locking a mutex can be expensive. It's better to check first, and only go to the trouble of locking if absolutely required.

As for why there are two checks. Imagine Thread A discovers that there is no `IOLoop` instance (i.e., does the first check). So it tries to lock the mutex. But before it can do so, Thread B locks the mutex, creates the singleton, and releases the mutex. Now Thread A can lock the mutex, but the singleton exists! It should not be created again, which is why its (non)existence must be verified a second time.